# Factorizing multivariate polynomials in $GF_2[x_1, ..., x_n]/[x_1+x_1^2,...]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, finite-fields, factoring, multivariate-polynomial

I'm trying to factorize multivariate polynomials in the quotient ring $GF_2[x_1, ..., x_n]/[x_1+x_1^2,...,x_n+x_n^2]$.

For example
$$
\begin{align}
f&=(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)(x_2 + x_4)(x_1 + x_4) \\
&=x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2^2+x_1x_2x_3+x_1^2x_4+x_2^2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4+x_1x_4^2+x_2x_4^2+x_3x_4^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
&= x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_3x_4 + x_3x_4 \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
$$

$\eqref{eq2}$ is the result of applying the quotient.

Sage Math allows me to factor polynomials like $\eqref{eq1}$ quite well, but not polynomials like $\eqref{eq2}$. Indeed in the case of $\eqref{eq2}$, all it produces is $x_3(x_1x_2 + x_1x_4 + x_2x_4 + x_4)$ whereas I would like to get all the linear factors as seen in the original poly. I'm not sure if this is simply a local optimum that it found, and maybe it could be coerced into looking specifically for only linear factors?

Is there an algorithm that is applicable specifically to factoring these sorts of polys (as seen in $\eqref{eq2}$) into linear factors? I've started looking into [Lenstra (1984)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2008063) and [Bernardin (1999)](https://doi.org/10.3929/ETHZ-A-003828824) which seem promising, but will take me a while due to my limited math experience, so a pointer in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Since $x_1(x_1+1)=0$, your ring isn't even an integral domain. In what sense do you expect factorization to be unique, or even to make sense?

Comment: A concrete example, using $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$. $(x+1)(x+y)=xy+y=y(x+1)$.

Comment: So I have constructed a fairly good factoring algorithm using Groebner bases. It extracted the two factorizations of your equation, yours and $x_4(x_2+x_4)(x_1+x_4)$ in a fraction of a second. It should work well up to around 20 variables. But you need a computer algebra package that has support for Groebner bases, such as Magma. Do you just need to do this a few times, or is this a problem you need to theoretically solve?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven That's awesome! Using a CAS is fine (I've used Sage Math before, which I think has Groebner bases support, but am amenable to others). I would like to do this for a large number of polys, but I haven't characterized it yet, so having something like what you've constructed is a good starting point to analyzing the feasibility of what I'm doing

Comment: @DavidA.Craven to your first comment, I'm working in the [Boolean Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) - maybe I didn't get the notation correct? I don't need factorization to be unique, just linear, so what you've created should work well

Comment: I've described a possible algorithm which is slow, and can be made more efficient, but depending on the number of times you want to run this, a few tens of thousands, maybe a couple of million, it's pointless speeding it up because doing so takes longer than leaving it to run. Indeed, for small numbers of variables one can just create lookup tables.

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are any affine linear forms in the variables $x_i$, we have the relation David pointed out: $uv=u(1+u+v)$. Using that repeatedly you easily find many ways of factoring $f$. With your example it could go by steps for example as follows
$$(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_2+x_4)(x_1+x_4)\to(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_2+x_4)(1+x_1+x_2)$$
$$\to x_3(x_2+x_4)(1+x_1+x_2)$$
$$\to x_3(x_2+x_4)(x_1+x_4)$$ with the obvious choices for $u$ and $v$ at each step.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that by basic linear algebra we can show that any two factorizations into affine linear forms can be gotten from each other by a sequence of steps like that. After all, $f$ is uniquely determined by the set of points where it takes value $1$, aka its *support*. But an affine linear form takes value $1$ on an affine hyperplane. The product of such beasts equals $1$ exactly in the intersection of the respective hyperplanes. It follows that if a degree $r$ polynomial   in $m$ boolean variables is a product of affine linear functions, then its support has size $2^{m-r}$.

Comment: A basic property of (binary) Reed-Muller codes says that the converse also holds. If a degree $r$ polynomial in $m$ boolean variables has support size $2^{m-r}$, then the support is the coset of an $(m-r)$-dimensional subspace of $GF(2)^m$. Then the support can easily be written as an intersection of $r$ codimension $1$ affine subspaces.

Comment: Alas, I don't see right away, if this can be turned into an efficient algorithm for finding those factorizations. My guess is that it can, but my intuition is not too well calibrated in such matters.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly difficult to produce an inefficient algorithm to solve this problem. For specific polynomials in a small (couple of dozen?) number of variables this isn't too hard. Let the number of variables be $n$, and let $f$ be the polynomial you need to factorize.

1. Enumerate all linear equations. There are $2^{n-1}$ of these. Call this set $X$.
2. For each $p\in X$, form the ideal $I_p=\langle p,x_i^2+x_i\rangle$. Use your CAS to produce a Groebner basis for this ideal so you can test membership.
3. For each $p$, check if $f\in I_p$. If it is, then there exists $g_p$ such that $f=p g_p$ modulo the relations $x_i^2+x_i$.
4. Use recursion to describe all possibilities.

Now Magma (possibly other CASes) allows you to write $f$ as an member of $I_p$ whenever $f$ lies in it. Perhaps a better alternative is:

4. Now you know all $p$ such that $p\mid f$ in this ring, just multiply them together in all ways to see which subsets of them multiply to $f$. It's probably faster than recursion.